# How to reference an app resource in a xaml Window?

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources, app.xaml, application-resource

I've added a reference to an app resource in my View's window. But when I declare the resource I get the error:

```
Error   10  RegexValidationRule is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project.
```

This is how I added the resource to the View:

```
  <Window.Resources>
        <validators:RegexValidationRule x:Key="localRegexValidationRule"/>
    </Window.Resources>
```

Does anyone know how to reference the resource correctly in WPF?

I've followed [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610259/how-to-add-more-that-one-resource-to-a-xaml-window) but still get the same error on the resource. This is how I've declared the resource in app.xaml within a resource dictionary:

```
<Application x:Class="MongoDBApp.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MongoDBApp.Converters"
             xmlns:validators="clr-namespace:MongoDBApp.Validators"
             StartupUri="pack://application:,,,/Views/MainView.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <converters:BoolToNonVisibilityConverter x:Key="localBoolToNonVisibilityConverter" />
            <converters:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="localBoolToVisibilityConverter" />
            <validators:RegexValidationRule x:Key="localRegexValidationRule" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: What about that validator? (validators:RegexValidationRule)
Sounds like it is compiled somehow strange.
Do you use Blend? ('cause I Googled and found: http://dotnetgui.blogspot.hu/2012/02/expression-blend-bugcant-open.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added the appropriate using statement in your View file? It should have the same statement as your App.xaml file:

```
         xmlns:validators="clr-namespace:MongoDBApp.Validators"
```